# USA analogue of EU Gastronorm standard

Tags: equipment, containers

What is the standard for kitchenware tray and container sizes in the USA, that is the analogue of the [Gastronorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastronorm) standard in EU? For instance the standard sizes used in salad bars.

Comment: As per linked wikipedia "commonly seen worldwide".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find an official standard for US sized pans... the wikipedia even state : "used worldwide except in the United States, **which has its own domestic system**" but does not link to any reference to that system.

[This](https://www.fwe.com/learn/A-Guide-to-Gastro-Norm-Pan-Sizes) seems to indicate that the Gastronorm was based on existing US standard :

"At this meeting the basic size of 530 x 325 mm, **already in use with American standard** steamable pans, was accepted."

[This](https://www.webstaurantstore.com/guide/556/food-pan-buying-guide.html) lists a series of sizes that seem to be accepted nationally in the USA and says that : "**Gastronorm sizes are comparable to American sizes and can generally be interchanged.**" (bold by me)

So you can safely use GN sized pans everywhere.

Comment: The standard size is 12"x 20", with derivatives based on fractional sizes. They're known as [hotel pans](https://www.vollrathfoodservice.com/culinary-experience-inspiration/vollrath-food-service-blog/layout-options-for-super-pan-and-super-shapes).

Comment: The best explanations I've seen on hotel pan sizing is from restaurants supply stores (like the one you linked to), but I've never seen an official "standard" like to describe what the minimum/maximum size of the lip should be, or the min/max radius of curvature in the corners (which affects how well different brands stack together without getting stuck), or even specifications for minimum widths & max radius of the corners in the tables themselves (as hot trays will expand, getting stuck in the table)

Comment: Yes, I don't think there is a specification on details. It's just "eh, we make them this size. It'll fit. Good enough!"